# Upload csv and read it as h2o object in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, h2o

Im trying to upload a csv file to a `shiny` app as a [h2o](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/index.html) object based on this [process](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/uploading-data.html) but I get `Warning: Error in .key.validate:` key `must match the regular expression '^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$': 0_sid_b018_4`. Im not sure if there is a problem with path reading or the table

```
#install h2o first
if ("package:h2o" %in% search()) { detach("package:h2o", unload=TRUE) }
if ("h2o" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) { remove.packages("h2o") }


if (! ("methods" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("methods") }
if (! ("statmod" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("statmod") }
if (! ("stats" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("stats") }
if (! ("graphics" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("graphics") }
if (! ("RCurl" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("RCurl") }
if (! ("jsonlite" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("jsonlite") }
if (! ("tools" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("tools") }
if (! ("utils" %in% rownames(installed.packages()))) { install.packages("utils") }


install.packages("h2o", type = "source", repos = (c("http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_R")))
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

#app
library(shiny)
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Define UI for data upload app ----
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      # Input: Select a file ----
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = FALSE,
                accept = c("text/csv",
                           "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".xlsx",
                           ".csv")),
      
      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),
      
      # Input: Checkbox if file has header ----
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      
      # Input: Select separator ----
      radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                   choices = c(Comma = ",",
                               Semicolon = ";",
                               Tab = "\t"),
                   selected = ","),
      
      # Input: Select quotes ----
      radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                   choices = c(None = "",
                               "Double Quote" = '"',
                               "Single Quote" = "'"),
                   selected = '"'),
      
      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),
      
      # Input: Select number of rows to display ----
      radioButtons("disp", "Display",
                   choices = c(Head = "head",
                               All = "all"),
                   selected = "head")
      
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Data file ----
      tableOutput("contents")
      
    )
    
  )
)

# Define server logic to read selected file ----
server <- function(input, output) {
  file_info <- reactive({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, head of that data file by default,
    # or all rows if selected, will be shown.
    
    req(input$file1)
   
      # when reading semicolon separated files,
      # having a comma separator causes `read.csv` to error
      tryCatch(
        {
          path <- input$file1$datapath
          data <- h2o.uploadFile(path = path)
          df <- read.csv(data,
                         header = input$header,
                         sep = input$sep,
                         quote = input$quote)
        },
        error = function(e) {
          # return a safeError if a parsing error occurs
          stop(safeError(e))
        }
      )
      
      if(input$disp == "head") {
        return(head(df))
      }
      else {
        return(df)
      }
    
    
  })
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    
    file_info()
  })
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see there 2 issues:

- H2O-3 requires its internal keys to start with a letter. The internal key is derived from the file name. When shiny uploads the file it renames it and in this case the file was named `0.csv`. To workaround this you can specify `destination_frame`, e.g.:

```
data <- h2o.uploadFile(path = path, destination_frame = paste0("file_", digest::digest(path)))
```

- The other issue is reading the csv. You use `read.csv(data)` where `data` is an H2OFrame, this will not work. You should use `as.data.frame(data)` or `read.csv(path, ...)`.

Comment: Error:'file' must be a character string or connection with as.data.frame()